# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have created a web client to send POST requests to a service. Please refer the code below:

```
webClient.post().uri("/v1/check/campaign-association")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(campaignAssociationRequestDTO))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(CampaignAssociationResponseDto.class);
```

When the code runs, this API is able to retrieve the result the first time we hit. But all the subsequent calls to this API results in the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:182)
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.subscribe(FluxReceive.java:143)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62)
at reactor.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:339)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4361)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:393)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:334)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxFilterFuseable.java:382)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onError(MonoCollect.java:144)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:165)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92)
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:167)
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.subscribe(FluxReceive.java:143)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62)
at reactor.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:339)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:388)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:130)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:173)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:189)
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:174)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:160)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:414)
at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:654)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:201)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:457)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:628)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I looked this exception up, and could see several stackover flow answers as well as some github issues. I already tried the below solutions as specified in them:

**First,** Disable the httpmethod filter property:

```
webflux:
    hiddenmethod:
        filter:
            enabled: ${HIDDEN_METHOD_FILTER_ENABLED:false}
```

**Second,** Creating the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` bean:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfig {
    @Bean
    public HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
        return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
            @Nonnull
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> filter(@Nonnull ServerWebExchange exchange, @Nonnull WebFilterChain chain) {
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Third,** Some even reported that it was an issue with the spring boot version `2.0.5`. But we are using spring boot version `2.5.5`

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

**Forth,** I could find ion certain sources that we can use `.share()` property of Mono stream. In the API documentation I found the following:

> Further Subscriber will share the same Subscription and therefore the
> same result. It's worth noting this is an un-cancellable Subscription.

When it says that subscriber will share the subscription and same result does that mean that any subsequent calls to this API even with different input will produce the same result always? If this is true, then we cannot use this.

Would someone help what could be going wring here?

Comment: you are reusing the connection, but you have posted way to little code to reproduce the problem. If i copy paste your 5 lines of code and place them in my idea, it all works fine. So you need to post more code and more context until we can solve your specific problem.